# React router - activeClassName on Link home

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with react router activeClassName on Link.

```
return (
      <div className="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to={'/'} activeClassName="active">
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to={'about'} activeClassName="active">
              About
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to={'freebies'} activeClassName="active">
              Freebies
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to={'sandbox'} activeClassName="active">
              Sandbox
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
```

The problem is when i am for exemple on link about, activeClassName work on this link but also in the home link too ' / '.

I don't know if someone have the same issue.

Thank you !

Comment: Did u use `<IndexRoute component={Home} />` to define your home route?

Comment: Yes @JamesChoi ! Exemple : <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have used `<IndexRoute component={Home} />` to render home component.

You should use IndexLink to provide link for Home page

```
<li><IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</IndexLink></li>
```

With that this ( **Home** ) link will be only "active" when we're at the index route.