# where to specify reacjs-router entrypoint of the application

Tags: reactjs, react-router

in my react app I want that the entrypoint is not localhost:3000/

it should be localhost:3000/dashboard

where can I set this?

Thanks, I've done it this way now, because my routse were in a routes file

```
{
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    sidebar: () => <div>home!</div>,
    main: () => <Dashboard />
},
```

can I specify an activeClassName for this link as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the IndexRoute for it.

```
<IndexRoute component={Dashobard} />
```

A good example is :

```
 <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Container}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='/address' component={Address} />
      <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

When you hit http://localhost:3000, Home component will render

Comment: I've added my code above how it works. can I specify an activeClassName for this link as well?

Comment: Please follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998290/react-router-activeclassname-on-link-home

Comment: Thanks tried this:  <li><IndexLink to="/dashboard" className="fa fa-bars fa-2x" activeClassName="activeSidebar"
                                  aria-hidden="true"></IndexLink></li>

But now the app is not rendering ... white page

Comment: I have not used activeClassName, so could not help. May be you can ask a question for that also. Thanks

Comment: Also it should be <li><IndexLink to="/" className="fa fa-bars fa-2x" activeClassName="activeSidebar" aria-hidden="true"></IndexLink></li>

Answer (score 1):

Your router configuration should similar to this:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to set in on webpack-dev-server, so in `webpack.config.js` you should set `publicPath` :

```
publicPath: "/dashboard",
```